# Extract Values from MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Tags: html, vba

I have managed to take a table and break it down into an `MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection`

Here is an example of the `tableCells.Item(1).innerHTML` which each item looks the same. I'm now looking to extract the values of `p_samptype` which would be `MyType` and also `3.8300`.

```
<TD>ABC123</TD>
<TD align=center><INPUT type=hidden value=001 name=p_ordno><B>001</B></TD>
<TD align=center><INPUT style="WIDTH: 165px" maxLength=40 value=123 name=p_sampdesc><INPUT type=hidden value=123 name=p_orig_sampdesc></TD>
<TD align=center><INPUT disabled id=p_samptype style="WIDTH: 115px" maxLength=15 value="MyType" name=p_samptype><SPAN style="WIDTH: 5px"></SPAN><INPUT type=hidden value="MyType" name=p_orig_samtype></INPUT><INPUT type=hidden value=1 name=p_tier></TD>
<TD align=right>3.8300</TD>
<TD align=center>2021/07/06</TD>
```

Here is how I get `tableCells`

```
 Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
 Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
 Dim tableCells As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
 Set tableCells = GetHTMLTable(URLStr, TableStr, doc)
 Debug.Print tableCells.Item(1).innerHTML
```

Comment: Which Office version are you running?

Comment: This needs to be able to run on Office 2013 and newer ideally x32/x64. I have a number of end users.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be declaring as MSHTML.HTMLTable then you can access with .rows() and .children()

e.g.

```
Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable: Set table = GetHTMLTable(URLStr, TableStr, doc)
Debug.Print table.rows(0).children(3).children(0).value
Debug.Print table.rows(0).children(4).innertext
```

Comment: I'm getting errors on both, unsupported :(

Comment: I'm guessing this is a private/login based url? Also, what does `Debug.Print typename(tableCells.Item(1))` return? Is there a reason why `GetHTMLTable` doesn't return an `MSHTML.HTMLTable`

Comment: `Debug.Print typename(tableCells.Item(1))` = `HTMLTableRow` . Also, you make me wonder if I'm doing things wrong, this is my first attempt scraping data from a webpage and I'm just using code I found on SO. Should I be using `MSHTML.HTMLTable`?

Comment: I posted how I got it working, but again, perhaps I need to step back and re-evaluate my approach?

Comment: `Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable: Set table = GetHTMLTable(URLStr, TableStr, doc)`

Comment: e.g. `table.rows(0).children(3).children(0).value` ; assuming your function correctly returns an HTMLTable which it seems it does.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect what I think you could use if declaring as HTMLTable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a mixture of

```
tableCells.Item(i).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText
```

and

```
tableCells.Item(i).getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innerHTML
```

The `innerHTML` will require further string manipulation though, but I'm unsure of a better way atm.